# Consume jira rest with java

Tags: json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

i'm using java and i want to consume the json in this url : http://jiraserver/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=13879&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository

on the browser this url works perfectly and i get all json data needed but in my java program i get

> **java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://jiraserver/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=13879&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out
                .println(jsonGetRequest("http://jiraserver/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=13879&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository
"));
          }

          private static String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
            String text = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            return text;
          }

          public static String jsonGetRequest(String urlQueryString) {
    String json = null;
        try {
          URL url = new URL(urlQueryString);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
          connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
          connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
          connection.connect();
          InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
          json = streamToString(inStream); // input stream to string
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
      }
```

am i missing something ? if there's any simple implementation to consume that url feel free

Comment: Kindly share error stack trace if available.

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: Your code seems to correct. Possibly URL that you trying to access require Authentication.

Comment: That's exactly the issue         String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userpass.getBytes()));